# Unexplained "cannot find symbol" error; symbol appears to be defined correctly

Tags: java

My assignment here was quite simple. It's a snippet of the whole assignment, but ultimately I need to insert a track into the LinkedList at the position indicated index. However, when I run my code checker I get the following error.

Running Tester

Compiler error:

```
/data/opt/codecheck/submissions/1411052126707049920533155043/Album.java:111: error: cannot find symbol
        tracks.add(index, t);
                   ^
  symbol:   variable index
  location: class Album
1 error
```

Any ideas?? I don't know why this is having issues. These are my instructions and my whole two lines of code. Thank you.

```
/**
 * addTrackAt. Insert a track into the LinkedList
 * at the position indicated index.
 * 
 * @param index where to insert
 * @param t the track to insert
 */
public void addTrackAt(int index, Track t) //provided
{
    tracks.add(index, t); // my code - but it's not working. I don't know why.
}
/**
 * removeTrackAt. Remove a track at a specific index.
 * 
 * @param index the index at which to remove
 */
public void removeTrackAt(int index) // provided
{
    tracks.remove(index); // my code
}

/**
 * getTrackAt. Return the track at the given index.
 * 
 * @param index the index at which to return
 * @return
 */
public Track getTrackAt(int index) //provided by instructor
{
    return tracks.get(index); // my code
}
```

Comment: The error means there is nothing named "index" in that context, but this error does not correspond to the code you posted, where you *do* have a variable named "index" - it *looks* OK. Are you positive that line 111 is the line in the snippet you posted? Are you sure you didn't make a mistake such as not saving your files in your editor before compiling them? Are you sure your "code checker" is using the most up-to-date version of your files?

Comment: Line 111 corresponds to the tracks.add(index, t) and the code checker code corresponds to my version. Basically I copy and paste the skeleton that my professor assigns us onto Eclipse, and then I fill in the slots back in the code checker.

Comment: @Eva A common gotcha in Eclipse is to not save the work before running it, because it doesn't autosave. Make sure all your files are saved, resubmit, and check to see if the results are the same. I don't really have any other advice, because as it stands the code you have posted looks fine and would not generate the error you describe. Something is off somewhere, and there's not enough info here to tell what it is.

Comment: @Eva Everything seems fine, you ought to be doing something wrong, Can you show us the declaration of `tracks` variable

Comment: @Eva show how u declare tracks?

Comment: The declaration of `tracks` is irrelevant to the compiler complaining about the variable named `index` not being defined...

Comment: how ever its not compete example code so its wont be possible to assue something that is what i am trying to say @JasonC

Comment: @Krishna For more information about the error message "cannot find symbol", see [here](http://java.about.com/od/cerrmsg/g/Definition-Cannot-Find-Symbol.htm).

Comment: @JasonC Yes , but I really cannot seem to find any problem.

Comment: @JasonC i have seen that already but do u think that is specific reason for that?

Comment: @Eva A long shot, but you say you copy + pasted the template code into Eclipse. Is it possible that some unprintable or funky control character made its way into your template? Just for giggles, try deleting "`addTrackAt(int index, Track t)`" then retyping it by hand.

Comment: @Krishna Of course it is the specific reason. The OP posted the actual error message she got. She didn't just make it up. The compiler doesn't randomly print errors either. It's very clear. But her code doesn't show that problem. So while it's true that there's something going on here that isn't posted, that "something" has nothing to do with `track` or any other snippets of code outside of the method containing the line identified in the error. It is something strange.

Comment: It's ok. I appreciate it everyone. This was my final, it involves another class. It's too much to show everything. But basically this one which is part of the Album class has the same code as my draft and I did not have this issue. So I just gotta move on. Maybe the tester is a bit off.

Comment: @JasonC i would like to modify that there is ofc problem and problem is only not declaration or something related that and that is into the  remaining code what is not posted yet

Comment: @Eva just try to put runnable example relative to this. i mean not in busy time but afterwards at least lets see what is exact problem is.

Comment: @JasonC yes that problem occurs to me too sometimes copy pasting from lync client into older versions of eclipse. But I dont think thats the error it shows, it think it shows `illegal character`

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example that you are asking for still your requirement is not clear so what i got from that you need to add element in specifi [See this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

where mention that for adding specific position there is one way

```
void    add(int index, E element)
Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.

public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add("Krishna");
        list.add("Krishna1");
        list.add("Krishna2");
        list.add("Krishna3");
        list.add("Krishna4");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }

        // now adding element
        list.add(5, "Krishna5");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
```

hope that will help.

```
OR
```

and if u getting error then first check that your list is having that much size of not

```
list.size();
```

Comment: This does not seem related at all to the error message that the OP is trying to diagnose, which is "cannot find symbol: index".

Comment: How to add an element into the LinkedList at an indicated position see the question/

Comment: I did see the question. It is more than just the title.

Comment: that is what i mean adding element have this method only.

Comment: The error seems to be `Cannot find symbol` , exceeding index limit would result in `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, i dont think`list.size()` check is necessary.

Comment: then may be possible that its not giving index into the integer or some how its getting differ.

Comment: Thats not possible, if the value of integer is being passed it will  be received. There is some other issue, which does not seem to be highlighted in the question.

Comment: @Mustafasabir that is what i trying to say some how its not getting integer position to add that is why issue is there and that is what issue is there is not other issue

Comment: But if the question seems unclear how can you post answer before-hand :) , Just saying. Although the title does say `How to add an element into the LinkedList....` , on reading the question it seems the problem is something else, and this is common in this community that the title does not depict exact problem.

Comment: @Mustafasabir i am getting what u saying 100% agree i tried to edit questions as way possible and for the ans that is only simple working example and i have provided the link for full methods of LinkedList. isnt it a way to solve ans? or we should provide full ans?